# Nested SQL Transactions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, rollback

I have two stored procedures, I call one stored procedure from another stored procedure and in both two stored procedures I use transactions. Below is the stored procedures,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spOuter]    
AS
BEGIN
    begin tran t1
    -- some sql queries..
    Exec spInner;

    commit tran t1
END


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spInner] 
AS
BEGIN

    begin tran t2
    – some sql queries.
    rollback tran t2

END
```

but when executing this, It shows error as shown below:

`Cannot roll back t2. No transaction or savepoint of that name was found.`

Can anybody explain why is it showing?

Comment: You're calling "spInsertInner" but the proc is named "spInner".  Have you given us the actual code?

Comment: @Charles  Sorry, my mistake, I corrected it.

Comment: If you rollback in the inner stored procedure and thus the inner transaction, **all** transactions are rolled back. So when you return from the inner stored procedure, there's no more transaction left to commit. SQL Server only "fakes" nested transactions - they don't really work as you might expect - [see Paul Randal's SQL Server Myth-a-day: nested transactions are real](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/) for more info

Comment: @marc_s so even if I avoid the transaction name in rollback tran in spInner, it will not work. so could you please tell me how can i rewrite the stored procedure?

Comment: Read that article I linked to! No, nested transactions in SQL Server really don't work as one might expect - the syntax is there, but not the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Read this articles, you will get some better ideas...

http://www.codemag.com/article/0305111

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Is there any idea how can I rewrite the sps?

Comment: SQL Server will not support nested transaction like as oracle or db2. So your inner roll back never work, it will leave an uncommited transaction at the end, so your database will not be in a consistent state after executing this outer procedure.

You should commit the inner transaction irrespective of what is happening, and write other stuff in outer proc only...



[Nesting Transactions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189336(v=sql.105).aspx)

This is the real issue you are facing.